# Chrome is showing different user agent css for h1 tag for 2 different site

Tags: css

Chrome is showing different user agent css for `<h1>` tag for 2 different sites.

`<h1>` in actual site : font size is: 1.5 em
`<h1>` in demo site   : font size is: 1.17 em

How can change user agent css (1.17 em) to 1.5 em.

If I add "font size is: 1.5 em" within `<h1>` tag it will match with actual site.
But again It is showing different size in IE (i.e. actual site vs demo site).

How can I get same font size as in actual site in all browser?

Comment: You will have to show some CSS. Maybe you have set the `font-size` on the `body` to different values?

Comment: If I add "font size is: 1.5 em" in body it will match with actaul site. But again It is showing different size in IE (ie.actual site vs demo site).

Comment: I have a question
How/Why chrome-user-agent-css is showing different font-size for h1 tag in two different site.?

Comment: Can't hurt to look at a using a [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)

Comment: That's because different browsers render things differently.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "user agent css"?